# loading doesn't work in server

Tags: jquery, loading, delay, server

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

function ShowLoadingModel(){
    delay(function(){
            $("form").remove("#divWholeBlock").append("<div id='divWholeBlock' name='WholeBlockLoadingScreen' class='modalBackground' style='text-align:center;top:0;left:0;z-index:20000;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%'><img id='wholeBlockLoadingImg' src='......../lxxxx64.gif' /></div>");
    }, 1000);
}

function HideLoadingModel(){
    delay(function(){
        if($("#divWholeBlock").length > 0){
            $("#divWholeBlock").remove();
        }
    },1000);
}

function Import() {
            ShowLoadingModel();
  ........
.......
}
```

I can't seem to make it showloading over the server (different machine). Locally works.

Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Thank You

Comment: Well, do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Are you wrapping your code in $(document).ready ?

Comment: @slen you can easily use BlockUI jquery plugin to do the same. refer link http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Jquery file and gif image is available in server correct path

Answer (score 0):

1. Your path (src='......../lxxxx64.gif') is a place holder or not?
2. Turn on developer tools, and go to network panel. Make sure there is a request sent to the address of the gif when ShowLoadingModel is invoked. And see if this is a wrong path or wrong logic.